# Docker + Nginx: Websocket returns 404 not found

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, websocket

I'm struggling on implementing a websocket connection between a SSL Server and the client.

**Architecture:**

- Proxy: Nginx
- Host: Docker (Swarm)
- Webserver: Node.js (express)
- Client (Postman, later vue.js)

**Nginx settings (app.conf):**

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    server_name search.app search.app.host.ads;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://search-service:3020;      # docker container
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

**search-server (server.js)**

```
async function startServer() {

    // variable definition
    server = express();

    // set http server
    let httpServer = http.createServer(server);

    // init loaders -> websocket is defined here
    loaders(server, httpServer);
}
```

**search-service (websocket.js)** (how is the websocket created?)

```
let wsSearch = new websocket.Server({ server: httpServer, path: "/socket/websocketSearch" });
```

The websocket is working properly on localhost using this url
`ws://localhost:3020/socket/websocketSearch`

After deploying on production site, the url will be
`wss://search.app.host.ads/socket/websocketSearch`

Trying to connect to production websocket using Postman returns following error:

Error: Unexpected server response: 404

- Handshake Details

  - Request URL: https://search.app.host.ads/socket/websocketSearch
  - Request Method: GET
  - Status Code: 404 Not Found
- Request Headers

  - Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
  - Sec-WebSocket-Key: gzRuxZ2QYTOladlXSenjmw==
  - Connection: Upgrade
  - Upgrade: websocket
  - Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
  - Host: search.app.host.ads
- Response Headers

  - Server: nginx/1.19.4
  - Date: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 13:07:45 GMT
  - Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  - Content-Length: 161
  - Connection: keep-alive
  - X-Powered-By: Express
  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  - Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
  - X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"

Which package do I use to implement websocket?

> [WS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) Version 7.5.3

I've followed several instructions like [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) or related StackOverflow issues. However, I didn't manage to connect to my websocket.

Do you have any idea, where is my fault?

Thanks in advance.

If any further information is needed, I try to provide it.

Best regards

Comment: Could you try this setup with ws instead of wss and port 80 instead of 443? Or I think you should offload the ssl in nginx...

Comment: Hi @KemalKaplan, thanks fpr the response. I've changed settings to port 80 for this route. Now. I got the Error: Unexpected Server Response 200.

Comment: Which protocol do you use? (i.e. what is the value of httpServer)